# Can Firebase be configured to use less AppEngine instance hours?

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase

I am trying to create a prototype using Firebase on AppEngine, and I keep hitting the 9-hour quota as described here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio#configuring_the_app_engine_backend_to_use_manual_scaling

The doc states the following:

> To use Firebase with App Engine standard environment, you must use manual scaling. This is because Firebase uses background threads to listen for changes and App Engine standard environment allows long-lived background threads only on manually scaled backend instances.

I am not using the Firebase realtime database features, so does it still need to spawn threads to listen for changes?  Is there a way to configure Firebase to not need these background threads, and therefore, not need manual scaling?

Answer (score -1):

To quote [the doc you linked](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio#configuring_the_app_engine_backend_to_use_manual_scaling):

> To use Firebase with App Engine standard environment, you must use manual scaling.

So to be able to interact with the Firebase Database from app engine, your instance must be set to manual scaling.

If you don't interact with the database, you might be able to use auto-scaling. But that depends on your use-case.

Comment: Yes, that is essentially my question.  If I don't use the real-time database, is there a configuration that will allow me to enable auto-scaling?

Comment: To quote the same doc I linked:

Comment: To quote the same doc I linked:
`This is because Firebase uses background threads to listen for changes and App Engine standard environment allows long-lived background threads only on manually scaled backend instances`
Are these background threads needed in all cases, even if I'm not using the real-time database features?  Is there a way initialize Firebase so it doesn't need these threads and therefore, doesn't need manual scaling?

Comment: That depends on the Firebase features that you *do* use.

Comment: I am only using authentication, messaging, and storage.

Comment: As far as I know, neither Storage nor Messaging have SDKs that run on App Engine. I am really trying to help here, but have no idea what you're looking to accomplish on App Engine.

Comment: The AppEngine component of my app only uses the Firebase SDK for authentication, so I'm trying to figure out if you can still use that without manual scaling, or at least turn off the background threads.

Comment: Firebase Authentication requires manual scaling as there is some async tasks used so I don't think you have an option here.